# Approximating min with p-norm

Tags: real-analysis

For nonnegative $x \in \mathbb{R}_+^n$, $p \geq 1$ I want to find $\epsilon_{n,p}$ such that

$$
\frac{n^{1/p}}{||1/x||_p} \geq \min (x) \geq \frac{n^{1/p}}{||1/x||_p} - \epsilon_{p,n} ||x||_\infty
$$

Here is how far I got.  Without loss of generality, take $||x||_\infty=1$, furthermore, let $x$ be the vector $(m,1,...,1)$, where $m$ is the minimum element of $x$.  Then our goal is to find the maximum value of

$$\epsilon_{n,p}(m) = \left(\frac{n}{p - 1 + m^{-p}}\right)^{1/p} - m$$

What is an upper bound on $\epsilon_{n,p}(m)$ on $m \in [0,1]$?

[See this plot for n=3, p=3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28%282%2bm%5E-3%29/3%29%5E%28-1/3%29-m%20for%20m%20=%200%20to%201)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Edit to answer the modified question:**]

For $p=1$, $\epsilon_{n,p}(m)=(n-1)m$ and there is no upper bound on $\epsilon$, so I will assume $p>1$.

The derivative of this new version of $\epsilon$ with respect to $m$ is

$$\epsilon'_{n,p}(m) = n^{1/p}m^{-(p+1)}\left(p - 1 + m^{-p}\right)^{-(p+1)/p} - 1\;.$$

Setting this to zero yields

$$n^{1/p}m^{-(p+1)}\left(p - 1 + m^{-p}\right)^{-(p+1)/p}=1\;,$$

$$n^{-1/(p+1)}m^{p}\left(p - 1 + m^{-p}\right)=1\;,\tag{1}$$

$$(p - 1)m^p + 1=n^{1/(p+1)}\;,$$

$$m=\left(\frac{n^{1/(p+1)}-1}{p-1}\right)^{1/p}\;.\tag{2}$$

Then using (1) to substitute $p - 1 + m^{-p}$ and (2) to substitute $m$ yields

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\epsilon_{n,p}(m)
&=&
\left(n^{1/p}n^{-1/(p(p+1))}-1\right)m
\\
&=&
\left(n^{1/(p+1)}-1\right)\left(\frac{n^{1/(p+1)}-1}{p-1}\right)^{1/p}
\\
&=&
\left(\frac{\left(n^{1/(p+1)}-1\right)^{p+1}}{p-1}\right)^{1/p}\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

For $n=3$, $p=3$, this is about $0.171$, in agreement with your plot. To show that this is always a global maximum, note that $\epsilon_{n,p}(m)$ goes to $0$ for $m\to0$ and to $-\infty$ for $m\to\infty$, so if the derivative vanishes at a single point, it must be a global maximum.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is another solution, though.  If you plot $\epsilon_p(m)$ over $[0,1]$ there is definitely a maximum.

Comment: @charles.y.zheng: I don't see how that could be. What $p$ are you using? Here's a plot for $p=3$ that has no maximum: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%282%2Bm%5E-3%29%5E%28-1%2F3%29-m+for+m+%3D+0+to+1

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, there was a typo in the original post.

Comment: @charles.y.zheng: When you edit your question such that correct answers become incorrect, it's good practice to make such edits visible (e.g. by adding "Edit" in bold or prepending "This is a corrected version of the question" or whatever) so that people won't be led to think the error is in the answer. I've edited my post to answer the modified question.

Comment: Noted, and thanks for the answer.